# Libgdx tiled gaps between tiles

Tags: libgdx

so I have a problem with tiled map, My map has gaps/texture bleeding, I read other questions with this problem but I could not get the one which works.
I'm using already made sprite sheet which includes all of tiles, so does enyone know the solution for it ? that I could make and I wont need to cut like 60 tiles from sprite sheet ?

Answer (score 1):

use texture filter **Nearest** not **Linear** since Linear user 4 surrounding texels to calculate actual color so when it is on the border of tile it will generate the gap. You can read about TextureFilter here:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403

and you set it just like:

```
    Sprite sprite;

    //now you are initializing the sprite...

    sprite.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

of course you can call **setFilter()** direct on texture if you have an access to it. If you don't because you create **tiledMap** from file you can try to iterate over tiles and set proper filter for every tile texture:

```
    Iterator<TiledMapTileSet> iter = tiledMap.getTileSets().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Iterator<TiledMapTile> iterTile = iter.next().iterator();

        while(iterTile.hasNext())
        {
            iterTile.next().getTextureRegion().getTexture().setFilter(...);
        }
    }
```

You can also just extrude your atlas in TexturePacker - it will double every pixel on the border so color blending wouldn't affect it

Comment: But I dont use atlas, i have only tiled map file and png of sprite sheet

Comment: then set to this .png texture texturefilter as Nearest - I've edited my answer adding a code how to do it

Comment: But what i need to do when I set sprite_sheet.png filters ? how can i set it for tiled ? because I'am using tiled to make maps.

Comment: I edited my answer again due to no code formatting in comments

Comment: The 'iterating over tiles' didnt worked, there still are gaps